# Could not find mozilla runtime error

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I had Lubuntu 15.10 (Wily) and I upgraded to latest version (Xenial)
Then I uninstalled the Firefox which came with the OS because I need the official version of Firefox. I downloaded the official version, unzipped and added to path. But it only works when I run it from its folder with .`/firefox` or from a `.desktop`. When I run without `./` I get "could not find mozilla runtime" error.

I can't just reinstall the OS version because I need the official Mozilla release.

Comment: It got fixed by itself after moving in root folder of home, so it's possible that was the cause.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks for tip @edwinksl . I'll wait a little more maybe someone knows how to configure mozilla runtime path anywhere , not just in the default folder so that way the answer is more complete.